# Regular Expression for repeating letters false and true?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an array of strings and I am attempting to filter the array of strings that contain repeating letters. However, two weird things are happening that I don't understand. Here is my code:

```
var array = ["aba", "aab", "baa"];

var pattern = /(\D)\1+/gi;

var filteredArr = array.filter(function(element){
    console.log(element);
    console.log(pattern.test(element));
    return pattern.test(element) != true;
});

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Some weird things happen. Within the filter function, I test if the regular expression is true or false and that goes as it should.

```
pattern.test("aba") = false;
pattern.test("aab") = true;
pattern.test("baa") = true;
```

However, if I test them outside of the function, "baa" seems to return false...which is weird right?

```
console.log(pattern.test("aba")); //returns false
console.log(pattern.test("aab")); //returns true
console.log(pattern.test("baa")); //returns false
```

Onto the next weird thing. The filter function SHOULD return the elements that do NOT pass (ie return false) the filter test. My expected output would be:

```
filteredArr = ["aba"];
```

However, with the way the code is, my output is:

```
filteredArr = ["aba", "aab", "baa"];
```

What's even more strange is that if I change the filter function to return the elements that DO pass (ie return true) the test, the expected output would be:

```
filteredArr = ["aab", "baa"];
```

However, the output that I receive is an empty array:

```
filteredArr = [];
```

I'm super confused. Is my regular expression wrong or am I perhaps attempting something that the filter function isn't able to do? Here is a fiddle with all of the code:

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zm721wd3/)

Comment: Please do some research before just posting a new question.

Comment: Remove the `g` flag.

Answer (score 2):

The strange behavior you're seeing is the result of the `g` modifier. Every call to `test` is advancing the pattern's `lastIndex` property, which makes the next call to `test()` begin at a later point in the string.

Here's the [MDN description of the `lastIndex` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex):

> This property is set only if the regular expression instance used the
>   "g" flag to indicate a global search. The following rules apply:
>
> - If `lastIndex` is greater than the length of the string, `test()` and `exec()` fail, then `lastIndex` is set to `0`.
> - If `lastIndex` is equal to the length of the string and if the regular expression matches the empty string, then the regular expression
>     matches input starting at `lastIndex`.
> - If `lastIndex` is equal to the length of the string and if the regular expression does not match the empty string, then the regular
>     expression mismatches input, and `lastIndex` is reset to `0`.
> - Otherwise, `lastIndex` is set to the next position following the most recent match.

You can verify this by adding `console.log(pattern.lastIndex);` to your `filter`:

```js
var array = ["aba", "aab", "baa"];

var pattern = /(\D)\1+/gi;

var filteredArr = array.filter(function(element){
  var test = pattern.test(element);
  console.log(element + ": " + test);
  console.log(pattern.lastIndex);
  return test;
});

console.log(filteredArr);
```

To fix your code, remove the `g` flag from the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a global regexp with `.test` which is problematic.

Consider the following dev console trace

```
$ var pattern = /(\D)\1+/gi;
undefined
$ pattern.lastIndex
0
$ pattern.test('xx')
true
$ pattern.lastIndex
2
$ pattern.test('xx')
false
$ pattern.lastIndex
0
```

The problem that you're running into is that `RegExp`s with the `g` flag resume checking at `lastIndex`, so if you check the same string twice in a row, you get different results.

You can manually reset `pattern.lastIndex = 0` or use a non-global `RegExp`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working example.

```js
var array = ["aba", "aab", "baa","bba","bab"];


var filteredArr = array.filter(function(element){
    console.log(element);
    //note that a constant is used instead of the var
    var t = /(\D)\1+?/gi.test(element);
    console.log(t);
    return !t;
});

console.log(filteredArr);
```

The issue with your code is here:

> Use test() whenever you want to know whether a pattern is found in a
>   string (similar to the String.prototype.search() method, difference is
>   that test() returns a boolean, whilst search() returns the index (or
>   -1 if not found); for more information (but slower execution) use the exec() method (similar to the String.prototype.match() method). As
>   with exec() (or in combination with it), test() called multiple times
>   on the same global regular expression instance **will advance past the**
>   **previous match**.

[RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)